# ImageMagick convert a SVG file results a blank image

Tags: imagemagick

I'm trying to convert a SVG file with a xlink:href for an image inside with ImageMagick using the command :

```
convert file.png result.png
```

But this gives me a blank png file, I'm sure that the problem comes from the image because others instructions are displayed in the png file. I can get it working by using the command :

```
convert msvg:file.svg result.png
```

Does someone knows how to make this work without the "msvg:" part? Because I have to do this with php-Imagick after and I can't add the "msvg:" in my php code.

SVG file :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<svg id="svg" width="1024" height="1024" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin">
    <image id="svg-image" x="0" y="0" width="1024" height="1024" product_id="4" xlink:href="coeur.png">
    </image>
    <rect x="10" y="10" width="80" height="80" fill="red"/>
</svg>
```

ImageMagick version : 6.7.7.10-5+deb7u3

Output of "convert -list format | grep SVG" :

```
MSVG  SVG       rw+   ImageMagick's own SVG internal renderer
SVG  SVG       rw+   Scalable Vector Graphics (RSVG 2.36.1)
SVGZ  SVG       rw+   Compressed Scalable Vector Graphics (RSVG 2.36.1)
```

Php code :

```
$im = new Imagick();
$draw = new ImagickDraw();
$im->readImageBlob($svgParse->asXML());
$im->setImagePage(0, 0, 0, 0);
$im->scaleImage($viewBox['2'],$viewBox['3'], false);
foreach($ListText as $text){
   $draw->setFont(Mage::getBaseDir('media').DS.'font'.DS.$text['font-family'].".ttf");
   $draw->setFontSize( $text['font-size'] );
   $draw->setFillColor ( $text['fill']);
   $im->annotateImage($draw, $text['x'], $text['y'], 0, $text['text']);
}
/*png settings*/
$im->setImageFormat("png32");
// FB image
$imFB = clone $im;
$imFB->resizeImage(1200,630,Imagick::FILTER_LANCZOS,1);
$imFB->writeImage($filename_FB);
$imFB->clear();
$imFB->destroy();
// TW image
$imTW = clone $im;
$imTW->resizeImage(280,150,Imagick::FILTER_LANCZOS,1);
$imTW->writeImage($filename_TW);
$imTW->clear();
$imTW->destroy();

$im->writeImage($filename);/*(or .jpg)*/

$im->clear();
$im->destroy();
```

Comment: If you are using imagick, can you also post your current PHP code?

Comment: I added my Php code to my post beacause it was too long for comments

Comment: For security, rsvg delegate is not loading external image resources. Try setting the MSVG format before reading the blob date with `$img->setFormat('MSVG');`

Comment: Your answer solved my problem, thank you, you are my savior of the day :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

emcconvilutionle's answer was the solution, I just had to write

```
$im->setFormat('MSVG');
```

before

```
$im->readImageBlob($svgParse->asXML());
```

Comment: Glad to help, and welcome to StackOverflow. Please accept your own answer so others with similar questions know this solution works.